# CSS Media Queries overlay each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to make my navigation bar menu button centered on the navigation bar when on smaller screens (changing margins). Still, each time I make another media query, the one before doesn't work anymore.
Does anyone know how to add a media query without "breaking" the one before, or does anyone know another solution to my problem that works?

Here's the CSS with media queries:

```
**/* NORMAL SMARTPHONE END */

/* NORMAL COMPUTER BEGINNING */
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    nav ul{
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }


    nav ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 80px;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
}
/* NORMAL COMPUTER END */


@media only screen and (max-width: 780px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 102px;
        margin-right: 45px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) and (min-width: 781px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 92px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 845px) and (min-width: 816px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 75px;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 900px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 45px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 815px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 87px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 570px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 181px;
        margin-right: 48px;
    }
    label.logo{
        margin-left: -10px;
    }
}


/* 
@media only screen and (max-width: 927px) and (min-width: 901px){
    .checkbtn{
        margin-top: 35px;
    }
}
 */**
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to re-order your queries, since CSS stands for *cascading* stylesheets.

Comment: Even with reordering, it doesn't work...